# How to add in Tween js in Three js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js, tweenjs

Hello I would like to ask something about Tween js and Three js. Actually I have created the particles and it can start rotate by using Three js.

[image: The complete particles]

But when I adding this coding then the rotation is stopped. I am added down at the particles render there.

```
var testing = document.getElementById("sphere");
var tween = new TWEEN.Tween({x: 0, y:0, rotation :0})
.to ({x:400,y:0, rotation:90},2000)
.onUpdate ( 

function (){
    testing.style.left = this.x +"px";
    }).start ();
}
function animate (){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    TWEEN.update();     
    }
```

Can I know what is the problem? Waiting for reply.Thanks

Comment: Any error messages in browser's console? At least here you didn't close `.onUpdate(`

Comment: Yup the problem have solved. But now the particles cannot tween. Just can rotate. Can I know what is the problem again?Thanks~:D

Comment: what type of renderer do you use? is `testing` a child of a scene or it's a child of an html-element? could you provide more information/code/jsfiddle?

Comment: renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
 
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
         
    render();

Comment: I am using WebGL Renderer..o.o